# Render content over SSL using Apache httpd and Node.js running on the same server

Tags: node.js, apache

I am running node.js application on port 8000 and Apache HTTP server on CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

https://nodejs.mydomain.com/demo/index.html -> returns 404

http://nodejs.mydomain.com:8000/demo/index.html -> returns the content with Non Secure on the browser.

```
OS :- CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
# node --version
v16.20.0
# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.57 (IUS)
Server built:   Apr  7 2023 14:49:47
#
#cd /etc/httpd/conf.d/
#cat httpdfrontend.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName nodejs.mydomain.com
    Redirect / https://nodejs.mydomain.com/
 </VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web
ServerName nodejs.mydomain.com
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/nodejs.mydomain.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/nodejs.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/nodejs.mydomain.com/chain.pem
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"

<Directory "/var/www/html/web">
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
        Require valid-user
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/html/web/.htpasswd
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#cd /etc/httpd/conf.d/
# cat nodejsbackendssl.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8000/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

# netstat -anp | grep 8000
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      23679/node
tcp6       0      0 192.168.0.116:8000      104.152.52.207:46601    ESTABLISHED 23679/node
tcp6       0      0 192.168.0.116:8000      172.16.16.45:50467      ESTABLISHED 23679/node
#
```

```
Nodejs code document root -> /var/www/html/nodejssl (Node Port 8000)
Website php code document root -> /var/www/html/web
```

I have modified the httpd config file

```
#cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpcode.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName nodejs.mydomain.com
    Redirect / https://nodejs.mydomain.com/
 </VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        #RewriteEngine on
        #RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ /robots.txt [NC, L]
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/phpcode/cardium-version-2/web
    ServerName nodejs.mydomain.com
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/nodejs.mydomain.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/nodejs.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/nodejs.mydomain.com/chain.pem
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/

<Directory "/var/www/html/phpcode/cardium-version-2/web">
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
        Require valid-user
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/html/phpcode/cardium-version-2/web/.htpasswd
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have set up a new server with the below details. I am running node.js application on port 3000 and Apache HTTP server on CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

```
# node --version
v16.20.0
# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.57 (IUS)
Server built:   Apr  7 2023 14:49:47
#
```

Nodejs code document root -> /var/www/html/nodejssl (Node Port 3000)

```
# pwd
/var/www/html/nodejssl
# ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 336 Jun 27 09:43 server.js
#
cat server.js
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Website php code document root -> /var/www/html/phpcode (Port 443)

```
#pwd
/var/www/html/phpcode/
# ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 336 Jun 27 09:43 index.html
#
#cat index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <p>This is a simple paragraph.</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

```
#cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpnodejs.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName phpnodejs.mydomain.com
    Redirect / https://phpnodejs.mydomain.com/
 </VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/phpcode
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        ServerName phpnodejs.mydomain.com
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/phpnodejs.mydomain.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/phpnodejs.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/phpnodejs.mydomain.com/chain.pem
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

When i hit https://phpnodejs.mydomain.com/nodejssl/server.js I see "Hello World" which works as expected but when i hit https://phpnodejs.mydomain.com/ I do not see the html code index.html file content. Is there a way to render both index.html and node.js server.js file? For example when i hit https://phpnodejs.mydomain.com/ it renders index.html file content and when i hit https://phpnodejs.mydomain.com/nodejssl/server.js it renders node.js server.js file content.

Please suggest and guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do i need to specify documentroot in /etc/httpd/conf.d/nodejsbackendssl.conf file to render index.html file based on httpd access log file reporting 404 in /var/log/httpd/access_log ?

`cat  /etc/httpd/conf.d/nodejsbackendssl.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web/demo
<Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8000/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: You have 1 VirtualHost on port 80 which redirects to 443.  Good.  In your 443 VirtualHost, add your ProxyPass to your Node there.  The second VirtualHost 80 you mention in the comments will not be used, since the other port 80 will take precedence.  Apache matches the first VirtualHost if finds, form top to bottom.  FYI: do not add content for your question in comments, edit your question.

Comment: @Nic3500 I have added the config file /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpcode.conf. The website is not working at all once i add ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/

Comment: You need to have: **1** *One* `VirtualHost *:80`, which redirects to https (443).  **2**  
 *One* `VirtualHost *:443` that handles the certificates *and* the proxy to your node.  **3** all other VirtualHost definitions need to be taken out.  **4** when you have multiple VirtualHost, on the same port, using the same ServerName (or ServerAlias), Apache only uses the first one it finds.  **5** You will need to comment out some configurations here, and keep 1 of each.  **6** Test your https first.  Once you have the https + proxy working, then you test your http -> https redirect VirtualHost.

Comment: Note you have one `VirtualHost *:443` in httpdfrontend.conf and another in phpcode.conf.  In alphabetical order, only the one from httpdfrontend.conf is used, and that one does not do proxy.  That is why I mention having only 1 VirtualHost per port (per ServerName - ServerAlias) before debugging configuration.

Comment: @Nic3500 I have tested the configs using a different server and have shared the new /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpnodejs.conf file. Thanks

Comment: *For example when i hit https://phpnodejs.mydomain.com/ it renders index.html file content*  Setup a DirectoryIndex directive in your 443 VirtualHost.

Comment: @Nic3500 I have added DirectoryIndex directive in <VirtualHost *:443>. I have shared the modified httpd config file /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpnodejs.conf above. I have followed https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/ExampleVhosts. The issue still persists.

Comment: @Nic3500 debug apache error log file -> http://sprunge.us/kndkvL

Comment: ok I see.  You `ProxyPass / ...`, hence every request is sent - always - to NodeJS.  If it should only answer on `nodejssl/server.js `, modify your ProxyPass with that path.  Then anything that is not `nodejssl/server.js ` will "stay" in Apache, and use your DirectoryIndex.